# User management solution for app / website

Tags: web-apps, mobile, authentication, user-management, login

This may be a very noob question, but I finally decided to ask here after spending a week working on it. I know a bit of php/mysql/js coding. No experience in mobile app development - and wanted a way to link my [framework7](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/) app (and also a web based html version) with a server-side user management and authentication. Initially thought of WordPress REST, but decided against it as wanted simpler solution.

I need help in finding an open source software that I can use to do user management (login, session etc). I have a website and an app for a simple service that I provide (for simplicity lets assume it to be quiz and grading for each user).

SO basic requirements are:

1. User authentication through app - and related process flow.
2. User wise data(quiz score) saving in mysql.

I have tried [hybridauth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/), [Opauth](http://opauth.org/) in social plugins.

CodeIgniter, userfrosting (too large - uses too many libraries) and huge(was just not able to make it work - apparently the help docs not for noobs like me) in others.

Moreover, these are ideally website solutions where the files accessed are hosted in the web server - unlike the app where files are in mobile. Since I am more of a hobby programmer and am not an expert, a good user guide / tutorial would be helpful.

Does anyone know any other solution that I can use to do user management for my app?
 WIll really appreciate your help as I have hit a deadend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should look at [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/), together with these contributed modules for it:

- [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services).
- [OAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth).
- [HybridAuth Social Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth).

Answer (score 2):

## Digits by Twitter

The Twitter company has launched a user-authentication system for app developers, called [Digits](https://get.digits.com). This is independent of Twitter accounts. I've not used it; not sure if this is a fit for your needs but possibly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into experimenting with dreamfactory, I didn't like how userfrosting doesn't have rest api service out of the box although you can extend it, but dreamfactory seems to have user management build in w/ a focus on rest api. https://www.dreamfactory.com/. I couldn't find any other solutions although there are many boilerplate user management code respositories on this laravel. dreamfactory does support upgrades so you can keep up to date w/ them.

list https://github.com/TimothyDJones/awesome-laravel.

Comment: Could you expand on why it fulfills all the requirements? Have a look here: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/6957